# How to use jclouds-chef API for accessing nodes and runlists

Tags: chef-infra, jclouds

I am first time user of jclouds and looking for the details of:
set up
configure the jclouds
samples  / references to use jclouds to identify the nodes / runlists from chef

can you please share details thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/ are the docs for the library. Use them.

Comment: Dear Coderanger...Thanks for the details....can you let me know if jclouds can be executed on windows os